# how to hide all values of a column on event OnPreviewClick using fastReport

Tags: delphi, report, fastreport

I'm trying hide values when I do a click on one of values of a row. But not all values just the column which I clicked.

See down Image of Demonstration

[image]

I want when I do a click on 12, change all  values of the column for 0 ou null and when a click again the values come back a original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `OnPreviewClick` event to the field you want to hide do like this:

```
procedure frxDBDataset1Field1OnPreviewClick(Sender: TfrxView; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: Integer; var Modified: Boolean);
begin
   if frxDBDataset1Field1.text = '' then
     frxDBDataset1Field1.text := '[frxDBDataset1."Field1"]'
   else  
     frxDBDataset1Field1.text := '';
   Report.ShowReport;  //this will refresh the report                                                                            
end;
```

Every time you click any value of the column it will hide/show.